# Xeditable with Select2 Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

I have an xeditable field that is dynamically shown.   I want to use select2 to update it.

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

        $('.marketing_event_id').editable({
            emptytext: ".....",
            url: "ajax_xeditable_update.php?table=appointments",
            source: promo_codes,
            select2: {
                width: 200,
                placeholder: 'Select promotion code...',
                allowClear: true,
            }
        });


    });

//get the promo codes for the select2 box for xeditable. put it outside of ajaxcomplete so it doesn't keep firing off for every appt!

    var promo_codes = [];

    $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php?what=location_promo_codes', function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index) {
            promo_codes.push({
                id: data[index].value,
                text: data[index].text
            });
        });

    });
```

The select2 box shows with all the JSON options properly to the user, but when an option is selected and the 'checkmark' button is selected to update the field, nothing happens.  I am watching the Network screen in Chrome and the URL for the Xeditable field doesn't even fire.

Here's what my html field looks like:

```
 echo '<h5>Promotion Code: <a href="#" class="marketing_event_id appointment' . $result->id . '" data-name="marketing_event_id" data-type="select2" data-value="';  if(!empty($result->marketing_event_id)) { echo $result->marketing_event_id; } echo '" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Enter the appointment promo code." data-pk="'. $result->id . '">' . $result->promo_code .'</a></h5>
```

The data fields are populated fine.  I don't see anything wrong there.

Here is a sample of the getJSON info that is being used to populate the select2:

```
 [{"value":"663","text":"christmas2015"},{"value":"651","text":"web08"},{"value":"658","text":"paper0815"}]
```

I'd be happy to provide more code if needed.

Can anyone explain why the URL doesn't fire when the field is updated?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, but I don't quite understand why this works.

I added a line of code to the xeditable area:

```
 $('.marketing_event_id').editable({
            emptytext: ".....",
            container: 'body',  <---- THIS IS WHAT I ADDED TO MAKE IT WORK!!!!
            url: "ajax_xeditable_update.php?table=appointments",
            source: promo_codes,
            select2: {
                width: 200,
                placeholder: 'Select promotion code...',
                allowClear: true,
            }
        });
```